# best practice on pushing staging development (database/uploads) to the live server

Tags: git, deployment

so I have the following setup:

1. my `local` wordpress copy has git repository
2. I create changes in my local wordpress copy
3. I make `git commits`
4. on my `live` server I just issue `git pull` from my git repo
5. My local and live server are now sync.

Its the best practice I have at the moment, but ofcourse I have issue with the database sync.

to avoid conflict as much as possible, I will have to get a fresh copy of my live server's database, pray that no one will create a new post or create a new comment. Use that database to develop locally, after development, upload that database to the live.

Its too much hassle.

Is there a method or deployment system or plugin that whatever I develop on  my local copy (database change, media upload, etc). will be saved in a single file.
Then that single file can be imported in the live server, and there won't be any conflict even if there has been updates in the live server already?

Hope somebody can share their best deployment practices.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use WordMove**. I have been using WordMove for deployment from last 3 months and it helps easily sync your local and live instance. 
And its very easy to use as well.

---

Wordmove is a gem that lets you automatically mirror local Wordpress installations and DB data back and forth from your local development machine to the remote staging server.

https://github.com/welaika/wordmove

Comment: cool share :) but seems like still have the same issue, it requires as `sync the live server first to our local copy` before we do any local development :S

Comment: You can pull changes from production to your local using `wordmove pull -du`. for more info watch this video. http://vimeo.com/74646861

Comment: yup, but if you think about it, once you pulled the data from live to local, all changes in the live: _new blog comments, another author creating a blog post, etc_ will be discarded when you issue the sync after developing from local to live :S

Comment: But i dont see a point in pushing database changes from local to you production server.

Comment: You can only push file changes from your local to production.

Comment: if you create a new post/page in local development, will it also be synced to the live server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59346/discussion-between-the-wolf-and-jitendra-rana).